# Operate on deeply nested React components

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible to wrap every component in my React component tree with a `<Wrapper>`?

My goal is to add a wrapper component to every component in any React tree. This is for a React devtool I'm working on releasing soon.

#### Current research:

I'm experimenting with the [top level API](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html) (e.g. using props.children & cloneElement), but not having much luck yet.

There are also some libraries that do react component tree walking, seeing if any of them work or how they do it:

- https://github.com/ctrlplusb/react-tree-walker
- https://fernandopasik.com/react-children-utilities/deep-map
- https://gist.github.com/dandelany/1ff06f4fa1f8d6f89c5e

**Before:**

```
<Top>
  <Child1 />
  <Child2>
    <SubChild />
  </Child2>
</Top>
```

**After:**

```
<Wrapper>
  <Top>
      <Wrapper>
         <Child1 />
      </Wrapper>
      <Wrapper>
        <Child2>
          <Wrapper>
            <SubChild />
          </Wrapper>
        </Child2>
      </Wrapper>
    </Top>
</Wrapper>
```

**Edit**: 
For clarity - I have a higher order component `<Wrapper>` that needs to be applied to all descendents (children of every level) of a React component (e.g. an `<App>`). It cannot have any knowledge of the children before hand / require altering the code of the children.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an hoc then use it explicitly in every component.
https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

Comment: Thanks - I should have specified this has to work on an arbitrary component tree where you can't wrap the components individually.